# I get "new transaction is queued, waiting for open operation to finish" when I use cordova SQLite

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova

I just started learning SQLite and I use only cordova without Ionic and I am trying to understand why I get the console return: "new transaction is queued, waiting for open operation to finish" when I try to do something with the database

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var myDB;
//Open Database Connection
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
function onDeviceReady(){
myDB = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "mySQLite.db", location: 'default'});
}
//Create new table
$("#createTable").click(function(){
    myDB.transaction(function(transaction) {
    transaction.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS phonegap_pro (id integer primary key, title text, desc text)', [],
        function(tx, result) {
            alert("Table created successfully");
        },
        function(error) {
              alert("Error occurred while creating the table.");
        });
    });
});

//Insert New Data
$("#insert").click(function(){
  var title="Hello";
  var desc="World";
  console.log(title +""+ desc);
  myDB.transaction(function(transaction) {
        var executeQuery = "INSERT INTO phonegap_pro (title, desc) VALUES (?,?)";
        transaction.executeSql(executeQuery, [title,desc]
            , function(tx, result) {
                 alert('Inserted');
            },
            function(error){
                 alert('Error occurred');
            });
    });
});

//Display Table Data
$("#showTable").click(function(){
  $("#TableData").html("");
  myDB.transaction(function(transaction) {
  transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM phonegap_pro', [], function (tx, results) {
       var len = results.rows.length, i;
       $("#rowCount").html(len);
       for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
          $("#TableData").append("<tr><td>"+results.rows.item(i).id+"</td><td>"+results.rows.item(i).title+"</td><td>"+results.rows.item(i).desc+"</td><td><a href='edit.html?id="+results.rows.item(i).id+"&title="+results.rows.item(i).title+"&desc="+results.rows.item(i).desc+"'>Edit</a> &nbsp;&nbsp; <a class='delete' href='#' id='"+results.rows.item(i).id+"'>Delete</a></td></tr>");
       }
    }, null);
  });
});



});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was testing it in the browser